# Convert HTML to PNG using ImageMagick

Tags: php, html, imagemagick

Is it possible to convert HTML to PNG file using ImageMagick?

I already looked at many options but, the documentation is too poor or not clear.

Also, Please suggest something regarding this.

Comment: HTML is markup that can be rendered in a web browser. It is not an image like a PNG.  Apples and oranges. Are you maybe looking at creating a screenshot?

Comment: There are a number of HTML2PDF or HTML2PS apps that you can use. If you must have a PNG, then convert the pdf or ps using ImageMagick to PNG. You may be able to do that all in ImageMagick, if you include one of the html2pdf or html2ps apps as a delegate to ImageMagick and then modify your delegates.xml file. See HTML format at https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php where it indicates you need html2ps

Comment: No with just imagemagick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No with ImageMagick as far as I know. If you can, install https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ on the server and call it from PHP with:

```
shell_exec ('wkhtmltopdf http://www.website.com /path/to/image.png');
```

Comment: Interesting. Could even make a PHP extension out of that looks like (turns out its netscape4 and a screen capturer).

Comment: thanks! ..looks like it is the best fit for my problem.. =)

Comment: If it works you can mark the answer as accepted and state the issue is solved for others too. Hope you solved it. Thanks